# Laravel Seeder, call to undefined method ::create

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have a Seeder for different models and one of them is giving me the following error when I try to `artisan db:seed`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::create() in C:\www\site\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 3155
```

Here's Event.php, the model that seems to cause the problem:

```
<?php

class Event extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'played_on');
    protected $table = 'events';

    // RELATIONSHIPS ----------------------------
    // Event has many Decks
    public function decks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Deck', 'decks_events', 'event_id', 'deck_id');
    }

}
```

Note: I added the `protected $table = 'events'` to try and see if this was causing the problem, I don't think it's required. Here is part of the Seeder. The `Deck` part works fine (in fact, I do see the 'Added some cards to some decks' message because it crashes)

```
    // Decks
    $deck_1 = Deck::create(array(
        'meta' => 'U/W Control',
        'player' => 'Cookie Monster'
    ));

    $deck_2 = Deck::create(array(
        'meta' => 'RDW',
        'player' => 'Suzy Waterbottle'
    ));

    // All 3 cards in Deck 1
    $card_1->decks()->attach($deck_1->id);
    $card_2->decks()->attach($deck_1->id);
    $card_3->decks()->attach($deck_1->id);
    // 2 cards in Deck 2
    $card_1->decks()->attach($deck_2->id);
    $card_2->decks()->attach($deck_2->id);

    $this->command->info('Added some cards to some decks');

    // Events
    $event_1 = Event::create(array(
        'name' => 'Super Duper Tourney',
        'played_on' => '07/05/2014'
    ));

    $deck_1->events()->attach($event_1->id);
    $deck_2->events()->attach($event_1->id);

    $this->command->info('Added decks to the event');
```

This leads me to believe that something wrong happens on the `$event_1 = Event::create` line but I can't figure out what as it looks exactly like the code used for `$deck_1`... and `$deck_2`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Event` is a "reserved" word in Laravel. You may have to change it or namespace your class.

So, instead of your Event model class, it is using Laravel Event, which is `Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher`.

It is actually an Alias we have on app/config/app.php.

Namespacing it:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Eloquent;

class Event extends Eloquent {

   ...

}
```

Using it namespaced:

```
<?php

use App\Event;

class Whatever {

    $event_1 = Event::create(array(
        'name' => 'Super Duper Tourney',
        'played_on' => '07/05/2014'
    ));

}
```

You may need to

```
composer dumpautoload
```

To refresh your autoloaded namespaces and classes.

Comment: That explains why the error I was getting came from some random file, makes a lot of sense! I did ``namespace App;`` and ``use App\Event;`` but I get ``Class 'App\Event not found'`` when running ``db:seed`` now. Do I need to enable anything else to use namespace?

Comment: Yeah, composer dumpautoload. Edited.

Comment: Perfect! Also add to use ``use Eloquent`` in the Event otherwise I got a similar error but about not finding Eloquent. Everything looks good now, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Edited so people don't get that same error.

Comment: Turns out I get a similar error right after (when it reaches the ``events()->attach`` about undefined method ``Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::newQuery()``. newQuery() is from ``Eloquent\Model`` I'm assuming it gets called by ``attach()``? Do I need to fix namespaces for events() as well?

Comment: This is something you have in your Deck model, the events relation, might be broken now you have a namespace.

Comment: Yup! Had to change an ``Event`` to ``App\Event``. All fixed now! Thanks a lot!